# How to open shapefile dataset using ArcGIS Pro SDK .NET?

Tags: .net, arcgis-pro-sdk

I write AddIn for ArcGIS Pro using ArcGIS Pro sdk.

I have a shapefile on my disk(for example "D:\Data\shapefile.shp").

How can I open this featureclass?

For gdb geodatabase is very simple

```
using (var gdb = new Geodatabase(path)) 
{
 var dataset = gdb.OpenDataset(); 
}
```

but folder is not geodatabase and this code didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (var shapefileFolder = new Shapefile(new DirectoryInfo(path))
{
    var dataset = shapefileFolder.OpenTable(shpfile);
}
```

Comment: It works in ArcGIS Pro SDK 1.4+