The type or namespace name 'Shapefile' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
I have added below namespaces though the Shapefile class is not coming in ArcGIS Pro SDK C# code in ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Controls.ProWindow
name spaces are
using ArcGIS.Core.Data;
using ArcGIS.Desktop.Core;
using ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

and code failed is
using (Shapefile shapefile = new Shapefile(shapefilePath))
        {
        }

Error I am getting as below

The type or namespace name 'Shapefile' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code link is as below
ShapeFile

Good question, how does one go about creating a shapefile in ArcGIS Pro SDK? all I can find is SchemaBuilder for creating geodatabase feature classes. It must have changed since 1.4.

@MichaelStimson So the code mentioned in the link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181562/how-to-open-shapefile-dataset-using-arcgis-pro-sdk-net will not work

You can use the FileSystemDatastore from the ArcGIS.Core.Data namespace.
The datastore is constructed with a folder path that contains shapefile(s) (I think CAD and Raster-files are possible as well).
Afterwards you can access the datasets. Here's a small example of how to do that:
using (var dataStore = new FileSystemDatastore(new FileSystemConnectionPath(new Uri(@"your\folder_path", UriKind.Absolute), FileSystemDatastoreType.Shapefile)))
{
    var definition = dataStore.OpenDataset<FeatureClass>("your_featureclass_name");
    {
        //...
    }
}


Did some research, they removed the Shapefile class with the release of ArcGIS Pro 2.0, take a look at the Migration guide for more information: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProSnippets-Migrating-to-2.0#arcgiscoredata

thanks ,this is the one i was searching
